# Java - JPA, introducing Table generator sequence, How to avoid SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: jpa

I have a table "MYTABLE" which has an ID & NAME as its column, mapped JPA entity is similar with class "MyPersistence" with attributes id & name.

This table already has few records with unique ids as:

```
ID              NAME                                                                  
----------  ---------------                                                                  
1254        DEV-SA12                                                                  
234         DEV-SA345
```

Earlier the ids were generated manually but now I want to introduce table sequence generator, the sequence which I am using is named as "MY_GEN" and has current value as 100 (Restriction** - cannot change).

As you can see for Id 234 is already there, so when the sequence reaches at 233 and creates a new id, and tries to assign it, I am getting the following exception

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DEV.MYTABLE_ID_PK) violated
```

Any ideas how to avoid this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you do know that `@TableGenerator` has an initial value on it?

Comment: I know and putting sequence initial value as Max(among all existing ids) i can avoid the exception, but it can not be done because of some restriction i just need to use the same sequence starting with 100.

Comment: I know its kind of difficult, but is there any way where code can check the id duplicate's and if its already there produce next sequence value ?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: well that is what JPA provides. So tell the person who imposed the restriction "starting with 100" when there is existing data.